# How to suppress openssl error output in C?

Tags: c, linux, openssl

I've got a bunch of unit tests which use an invalid cert to provoke an error condition, this works perfectly but unfortunately my neat terminal output is now saturated with ugly OpenSSL errors, does anyone know how I can suppress these errors?

EDIT1: There errors look like this:

140376922039968:error:0906D06C:lib(9):func(109):reason(108):pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: CERTIFICATE
140376922039968:error:0D0680A8:lib(13):func(104):reason(168):tasn_dec.c:1319:
140376922039968:error:0D07803A:lib(13):func(120):reason(58):tasn_dec.c:381:Type=X509
140376922039968:error:0906700D:lib(9):func(103):reason(13):pem_oth.c:83:
140376922039968:error:0D0680A8:lib(13):func(104):reason(168):tasn_dec.c:1319:
140376922039968:error:0D07803A:lib(13):func(120):reason(58):tasn_dec.c:381:Type=X509
140376922039968:error:0906700D:lib(9):func(103):reason(13):pem_oth.c:83:

These are generated when I pass in an invalid X.509 cert to the OpenSSL X509 PEM decode function. The code that generates these errors follows:

```
    BIO *certBio = BIO_new_mem_buf(certData, certSize);
    X509 *x509 = PEM_read_bio_X509(certBio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

EDIT2: Sorry, my bad, I was calling the print errors function in my code, my apologies to those who spared some time to look into this :(

Comment: Redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`?

Comment: Could you show some of these "ugly" OpenSSL errors?

Comment: I still can't reproduce. Please show us the complete, working code.

Comment: I'm terribly embarrassed, I created a small demo but was unable to reproduce, after looking into my code I see I was calling 'ERR_print_errors_fp' :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried a few OpenSSL samples and I don't really see OpenSSL forcedly outputting anything to the terminal.

Thus, I will suggest a very simple solution: remove the error output commands from your test programs. You should probably look for `ERR_print_errors()`, `ERR_print_errors_fp()` calls, and possibly other output functions grabbing `ERR_reason_error_string()`.

If your code outputs errors nonetheless, please provide a sample which we could test and find out *why* that happens.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect `stderr`, where OpenSSL prints the errors, to `/dev/null` as follows:

```
./your_unit_test 2>/dev/null
```

You can also redirect it programmatically using something like:

```
  fclose(stderr);
  stderr = fopen("/dev/null","w");
```

Alternatively you could perhaps use `grep` to remove the OpenSSL lines if they always contain something specific. For instance,

```
./your_unit_test | grep -v OpenSSL
```

Comment: I'm looking for something more along the lines of suppressing *only* OpenSSL

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: maybe try `grep` then?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might work would be to switch over stderr to be a pipe and have another thread/process read from that pipe and filter out the messages you don't want.  Something like this might work:

```
// Error checking omitted for expository purposes
int origStderr;
int stderrFilter[2];

void RunTests()
{
    // Save original stderr
    origStderr = dup(STDERR_FILENO);

    // Create pipe to be used for filtering out OpenSSL messages
    pipe(stderrFilter);

    // Move the writing end of the pipe onto stderr
    dup2(pipe[0], STDERR_FILENO);
    close(pipe[0]);

    // Create thread to read from the pipe
    pid_t filterThread;
    pthread_create(&filterThread, NULL, &StderrFilterThreadProc, NULL);

    // Ok, run the actual unit tests
    RunOpenSSLUnitTests();

    // Close down the pipe, join the thread, and restore stderr
    dup2(origStderr, STDERR_FILENO);
    close(origStderr);
    pthread_join(filterThread, NULL);
    close(stderrFilter[1]);
}

void *StderrFilterThreadProc(void *arg)
{
    char buffer[SOME_REASONABLY_LARGE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int n;

    while((n = read(stderrFilter[1], buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        // Parse buffer into lines, determine if each line was an OpenSSL message
        for(each line in buffer)
        {
            if(line came did not come from OpenSSL)
                write(origStderr, line, line_length);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```